# How to access attributes from connection table in many-to-many relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `User` and a model `Band`. They have many to many relation using `has_many :through`, so I also have `BandUser` model. The connection table has several addition attributes including a flag called `started`.

I have a view rendering list of users in particular band. The each user is rendered in partial `_user`. In previous version I had one-to-many relation and just passed `collection: @band.users` to render method, checking `sterted?` there. Having many-to-many relation I can't do it because the flag is placed in another table.

So how should I check the flags located in connection table in views? What is the best way to check them? May be adding some method to UserDecorator such as `started_in_band(band)` ?

Comment: When you say many to many relation, is it `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`?

Comment: @Pavan `has_many :through`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to rename your `BandUser` model to something more descriptive, like `Membership`.

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :user
end

class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :bands, through: :memberships
end
```

You can then use `band.users` to get to the users directly, or `band.memberships` to get to the membership data where your `started` and other attributes are located.

The key point is that you need a separate `has_many` relationship to your intermediary model.

Answer (score 0):

```
band.users.where('bandusers.started IS NOT NULL')
```

should do it